# Match one to many columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 datasets in CSV file, using pandas each file is converted into 2 different dataframes.

I want to find similar companies based on their url. I'm able to find similar companies based on 1 field (Rule1), but I want to compare more efficiently as following:

**Dataset 1**

```
uuid, company_name, website
YAHOO,Yahoo,yahoo.com    
CSCO,Cisco,cisco.com
APPL,Apple,
```

**Dataset 2**

```
company_name, company_website, support_website, privacy_website
Yahoo,,yahoo.com,yahoo.com
Google,google.com,,
Cisco,,,cisco.com
```

**Result Dataset**

```
company_name, company_website, support_website, privacy_website, uuid
Yahoo,,yahoo.com,yahoo.com,YAHOO
Google,google.com,,
Cisco,,,cisco.com,CSCO
```

- Dataset1 contains ~50K records.
- Dataset2 contains ~4M records.

**Rules**

1. If field **website** in dataset 1 is the same as field **company_website** in dataset 2, extract identifier.
2. If not match, check if field **website** in dataset 1 is the same as field **support_website** in dataset 2, extract identifier.
3. If not match, check if field **website** in dataset 1 is the same as field **privacy_website** in dataset 2, extract identifier.
4. If not match, check if field **company_name** in dataset 1 is the same as field **company_name** in dataset 2, extract identifier.
5. If not matches return record and identifier field (UUID) will be empty.

Here is my current function:

```
def MatchCompanies(
    companies: pandas.Dataframe,
    competitor_companies: pandas.Dataframe) -> Optional[Sequence[str]]:
  """Find Competitor companies in companies dataframe and generate a new list.

  Args:
    companies: A dataframe with company information from CSV file.
    competitor_companies: A dataframe with Competitor information from CSV file.

  Returns:
    A sequence of matched companies and their UUID.

  Raises:
    ValueError: No companies found.
  """

  if _IsEmpty(companies):
    raise ValueError('No companies found')
  # Clean up empty fields. Use extra space to avoid matching on empty TLD.
  companies.fillna({'website': ' '}, inplace=True)
  competitor_companies = competitor_companies.fillna('')
  logging.info('Found: %d records.', len(competitor_companies))
  # Rename column to TLD to compare matching companies.
  companies.rename(columns={'website': 'tld'}, inplace=True)
  logging.info('Cleaning up company name.')
  companies.company_name = companies.company_name.apply(_NormalizeText)
  competitor_companies.company_name = competitor_companies.company_name.apply(
      _NormalizeText)
  # Rename column to TLD since Competitor already contains TLD in company_website.
  competitor_companies.rename(columns={'company_website': 'tld'}, inplace=True)
  logging.info('Extracting UUID')
  merge_tld = competitor_companies.merge(
      companies[['tld', 'uuid']], on='tld', how='left')
  # Extracts UUID for company name matches.
  competitor_companies = competitor_companies.merge(
      companies[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='company_name', how='left')
  # Combines dataframes.
  competitor_companies['uuid'] = competitor_companies['uuid'].combine_first(
      merge_tld['uuid'])
  match_companies = len(
      competitor_companies[competitor_companies['uuid'].notnull()])
  total_companies = len(competitor_companies)
  logging.info('Results found: %d out of %d', match_companies, total_companies)
  competitor_companies.rename(columns={'tld': 'company_website'}, inplace=True)
  return competitor_companies
```

Looking for advise in which function to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html), but one requrement is necessary - always unique values in `df1['website']` and `df1['company_name']`:

```
df1 = df1.dropna()
s1 = df1.set_index('website')['uuid']
s2 = df1.set_index('company_name')['uuid']

w1 = df2['company_website'].map(s1)
w2 = df2['support_website'].map(s1)
w3 = df2['privacy_website'].map(s1)
c = df2['company_name'].map(s2)

df2['uuid'] = w1.combine_first(w2).combine_first(w3).combine_first(c)
print (df2)
  company_name company_website support_website privacy_website   uuid
0        Yahoo             NaN       yahoo.com       yahoo.com  YAHOO
1       Google      google.com             NaN             NaN    NaN
2        Cisco             NaN             NaN       cisco.com   CSCO
```

Comment: Sorry, small typo, `c = df2['company_name'].map(s1)` to `c = df2['company_name'].map(s2)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a workaround where I have duplicated companies in df1 (company_name). I currently get "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" as seems to be I have dups.

Comment: @spicyramen - yes, exactly. So 2  possible solutions - remove dupes by `df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('website')` or aggregate `join` like  `df1 = df1.groupby('website')['uuid'].apply(', '.join)`

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [dataframe.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Rename third column in A to `company_website` and do something like

```
A.merge(B, on='company_website', indicator=True)
```

should at least take care of the first rule.

Comment: sorry missed that in the question. So is your question on the next rules, can't merge be used again? Are you looking for a more efficient method which applies all rules at the same time?

Comment: Thanks Gashem, I think merge may overwrite previously found values. Meaning if company_website is found, It overwrites results when run again.

Comment: I see. The `combine_first` suggested by @jezrael seems to do the trick.